Why/does 'low-dimension' topology end with dimension 4?
Put another way, assuming it is somewhat fair to say that we (not I, but those who know better--part of my question is whether my stated assumption is in fact warranted) have in some sense a qualitatively better handle on manifolds up to and including dimension 4 than we do for the case of 5+ dimensions, is it just a coincidence (i.e., 'non-mathematical' factors) that it seems 'natural' for us to think of space-time in terms a four-dimensional manifold?
Edit: apologies for my naivety; I do not mean to imply that my assumption is solid. I probably overestimated the legitimacy of the question I was asking.

One reason comes from the fundamental group. For two-manifolds, they are all defined by one relation and much is known; in three-manifolds they form a rich landscape with much both in the ways of decidability and mystery. But in four-manifolds (and above) the fundamental group can be any finitely presented group, and all hope of fully general theorems disappears.

@Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I know very little about this field, but that sounds like a good reason to have a cutoff at dimension 3 rather than 4

I suspect that an answer to your question is already among the answers here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47569/what-makes-four-dimensions-special

A major point is certainly that the h-cobordism theorem (in the smooth category) is true in dimension at least 5, but not in dimension 4 and presumably also not in dimension 3 (and has a very different proof in dimension 2).

Not everyone agrees that 5-manifolds (perhaps with boundary) are beyond the low-dimensional: eg see here

The term "low-dimensional topology" was created because of the Whitney trick and the h-cobordism theorem.  Roughly speaking, these tools made manifold theory (for many/most purposes) much more uniform and algebraic in nature, in dimensions $n \geq  5$.

@mme I should point out that my 'source' is Wikipedia (Geometric topology): "High-dimensional topology refers to manifolds of dimension 5 and above ... Low-dimensional topology is concerned with questions in dimensions up to 4, or embeddings in codimension up to 2. Dimension 4 is special, in that in some respects ... dimension 4 is high-dimensional, while in other respects ..., dimension 4 is low-dimensional."

''Is it just a coincidence (i.e., 'non-mathematical' factors) that it seems 'natural' for us to think of space-time in terms a four-dimensional manifold?'' I think it's basically a coincidence.

Contrary to the assumption in your question, understanding manifolds of dimension 5 and higher is considered to be easier than understanding 3- and 4-dimensional manifolds.  Why? Because in $({\ge}5)$-manifolds there is more room to maneuver.  Specifically, in a $({\ge}5)$-manifold any pair of embedded surfaces can be made disjoint by a small perturbation.  This fact leads to the proof of the $h$-cobordism theorem and other tools for classifying $({\ge}5)$-manifolds.
I'm not aware of any convincing argument relating the above to the fact the space-time is 4-dimensional.  But there is plenty of sub-convincing speculation on this topic.

Making embedded surfaces disjoint via perturbation is the "Whitney trick," right?

@Neal: No, that’s not what the Whitney trick is.  It’s a geometric move for cancelling intersections; see here: https://celebratio.org/Whitney_H/article/220/

Thank you for the response and reference!

Making smooth submanifolds of dimensions K and L disjoint by a small perturbation in a smooth N manifold is an easy consequence of transversality when K + L  <  N.

Now I want to write a paper with a section titled "Sub-convincing speculations"

So do I have it backwards? Is it that, contra my assumption, it is often easier to study 'low-dimensional topology' due to the number of dimensions required to perform the Whitney trick and perform surgery?

"Convincing sub-speculations", for vague philosophising below the level of actual concrete ideas, but that everything takes as a good motivating idea

@Municipal-Chinook-7: Don't you mean to say it's more difficult to study low-dimensional topology?  Because you appear to be re-stating your previously-stated assumption.

@RyanBudney yes, good point.

@Municipal-Chinook-7 Yes, your original question had it backwards (in my and many others' opinion).  Higher dimensional manifolds are in some sense easier to study and classify.

Would it be possible to give more detail on "in some sense". In other words, is it fair to say that higher-dimensional manifolds are easier to study and classify specifically in the setting of smooth manifolds that are simply-connected (or have sufficiently small fundamental group)? Here I mean difficulty relevant for present research - i.e. Freedman's theorem and Pereleman's theorem were hard to prove but low-dimensional topology is mostly not concerned with extending the techniques of that proof.

@WillSawin There are regular MO users who are much more knowledgeable on these matters than I am, so I hesitate to give a detailed answer to your question.  The reason I hedged with "in some sense" is that while in higher dimensions it is (relatively) easy to reduce topological questions to homotopical or algebraic questions, the resulting homotopical/algebraic questions might themselves be difficult.  Ryan Budney's answer alludes to this, I think.

There are of course ways to construct difficult problems in high-dimensional manifold theory.   One of the ways high-dimensional manifold theory differs strongly from low-dimensional manifold theory is in the study of automorphism groups, like the diffeomorphism group of a manifold.  In this case, dimensions $n \leq 3$ is very well understood, but dimensions $n \geq 4$ are considerably more difficult, and in many respects dimension $4$ more closely resembles high-dimensions than low dimensions, as far as we can tell at the moment.
But your question is specifically about what the term low-dimensional topology means.  And this is tied to the story of the classification of manifolds, and the tools we developed for the task, like the Whitney trick and h-cobordism.
Here is maybe an analogy to help understand how h-cobordism makes life easier in high dimensions. If you are studying a  rock pile and someone asks you to classify all the granite rocks in the pile.  If you didn't know any better you would have to pick through all the rocks and investigate them one by one.  Maybe you'd have to split some rocks if you were suspicious granite was fused into the centre of another rock.   But if you have a magical rock sifter that could pick out all the granite for you, it would be quick and easy.  h-cobordism is something like that magical rock sifter as it allows you to readily identify all the manifolds that satisfy certain homotopy properties. I like to think of it as something that makes the subject more uniform and homogenous -- it allows you to quickly find the things you are looking for.  Low-dimensional topology is less uniform so you have a harder time finding out if certain types of manifolds exist. Like, say, a counter-example to the generalized Poincare conjecture.

Ah, I recall seeing somewhere the notion that difficulties in high-dimensional topology are often explicitly homotopy-theoretic in nature. I'd assume that it would be a consequence of the h-cobordism theorem?

Not purely h-cobordism, but the h-cobordism theorem is the beginning of a body of work including what gets called "surgery theory", s-cobordism, k-theory, smoothing theory, and so on.  With only a few exceptions this body of work is coherent in dimensions $n \geq 5$, like the Whitney trick.
