# When is a compact topological 4-manifold a CW complex?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, open-problems, 4-manifolds, cw-complexes, topological-manifolds

Freedman's $E_8$-manifold is nontriangulable, as proved on page (xvi) of the Akbulut-McCarthy 1990 Princeton Mathematical Notes "Casson's invariant for oriented homology 3-spheres". 
Kirby showed that a compact 4-manifold has a handlebody structure if and only if it is smoothable:
[1](http://www.manifoldatlas.him.uni-bonn.de/index.php/Questions_about_surgery_theory) and [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7921/failure-of-smoothing-theory-for-topological-4-manifolds/38739#38739). When is a compact topological 4-manifold a CW complex?

Comment: I take it this is an open problem?  Small note, but your question was effectively asked in another form, here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36838/are-non-pl-manifolds-cw-complexes  I usually think of CW-complexes as being a tool for describing homotopy-types rather than homeomorphism types, so my answer was to a weaker question than the one asked. 

Comment: I have good reason to believe that it is an open question!
Apologies - I hadn't seen the earlier posting 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36838/are-non-pl-manifolds-cw-complexes


Answer (score -3):

Hatcher, Algebraic Topology, Corolary A.9

> Every compact manifold, with or without boundary, is an E[uclidean]N[eighborhood]R[etract].

See also the following three numbered conclusions.

Or, in simpler terms, CW is *a lot* more flexible than, say, PL.

---

By "compact manifold", I expect you mean, in particular, an object $X$ with a finite very good cover --- where, in case I need to be so careful, by "very" good cover, I mean that the boundary of every intersection of the Čech complex is a sphere.  Without Loss Of Generality, every compact manifold has such a cover.

So fix one finite good cover, and refine it to a finite good cover by closed sets.  Construe the Čech complex of this good finite closed cover as a simplicial-set-over $X$. Its realization has the homotopy type of both $X$ (it is fiberwise finite contractible) and a CW complex: roughly, each open patch of the Čech complex is a cone over a sphere, and there are finitely many, so we are iteratively gluing in a finite family of products $\triangle^n \times C(\mathbb{S}^k)$.  This *doesn't* literally produce a CW complex, in that the attaching of cells isn't in cellular order; however it *is* a finite process, amenable to iterative correction, and the Reader can supply the details as needed.

---

Since you mention Handlebodies I wonder: are you *actually* trying to get at which $4$-manifolds are **homeomorphically** *4-dimensional* CW-complexes?

Comment: Yes, the point is to determine when a 4-manifold is **homeomorphic** to a CW complex. See also Question 1.3 [here](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/index.php/Questions_about_surgery_theory)

Comment: A compact 4-manifold is a compact topological space which is locally homeomorphic to R^4. Borsuk proved in the 1930's that  compact topological manifolds (in all dimensions) are ENR's. But without differentiable structure, it is by no means clear that a topological manifold has a good cover. And yes, I do mean to get at compact 4-manifolds which are homeomorphic to (and so are) 4-dimensional CW complexes.