# Covering image of a connected CW-complex need not be a CW-complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, counterexamples, cw-complexes, covering-spaces

This question is already asked here [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981109/covering-image-of-a-connected-cw-complex-need-not-be-a-cw-complex), and there is an answer based on some conjecture ([probably still open](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73428/when-is-a-compact-topological-4-manifold-a-cw-complex)). I am posting the same question for a counterexample (if any, not based on such unsolved conjecture).

---

> **Problem:** Let $X$ be a connected CW-complex, and $Y$ be a connected topological space. Suppose $p: X\to Y$ is a covering map. Does there
> exist a CW-structure on $Y$? Is $Y$ homotopically equivalent to a CW-complex?

Note that the other direction is clear: Any covering of a connected CW-complex can always be given a CW-structure, lifting the characteristics map of cells of base space such that the covering map is a cellular map.

I believe that the answer to the above problem is no, but I have no counterexample.

- Notice that $Y$ is locally path-connected as the covering map is a local homeomorphism, hence $Y$ is path-connected also. So, we can not consider spaces $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ or Topologist Sine Curve as $Y$. [Notice that both $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ or Topologist Sine Curve are not homotopically equivalent to a CW-complex.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523416/is-there-any-example-of-space-not-having-the-homotopy-type-of-a-cw-complex)
- Similarly, we can not consider the [Hawaiian Earring (this is not semi-locally simply connected)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104275/why-is-hawaiian-earring-not-semilocally-simply-connected) as $Y$: The connected CW-complex $X$ has a universal cover, so that $X$ is semi-locally simply connected, but the property "semi-locally simply connected" is preserved under a local homeomorphism.

Comment: If $Y$ is locally-compact then it will be a metrizable ANR, hence, homotopy-equivalent to a CW complex.

Comment: I think an example is given in Exercise 1.3.25 of Hatcher. There is a covering space action of Z on the punctured plane with non-Hausdorff orbit spaces (call it Y) with fundamental group Z^2. Any map from Y to a Hausdorff space factors through a Hausdorffizafion Haus(Y). This space Haus(Y) is homeomorphic to S^1 x X, where X = R sqcup_0 R (the literal letter X without its endpoints). This has fundamental group Z. Hence any map from Y to a CW complex induces a map on pi_1 with cyclic image; there is no CW complex Y' with f: Y -> Y' which is an isomorphism on pi_1, as Z^2 is not cyclic.